# Определяем геолокацию пользователя Laravel

Tags: laravel, геолокация

Не подскажите как правильно реализовать.
Для определения города по IP использую  следующий пакет "scriptixru/sypexgeo": "0.2.*@dev".
в view проверяю(то есть на js вcплывает окошко "Ваш город N ?" если да пишу в куки , если нет - открывается страница выборки).
Далее если пользователь авторизован - надо записать в базу и сделать выборку по выбранному городу, если нет - просто сделать выборку по кукам . Подскажите как это правильно реализовать - с помощью Middleware.

Comment: В сессии храните город пользователя (для неавторизованного, для авторизованного берёте город из базы). Если города в сессии нет, то с помощью ПО редиректите пользователя на страницу выбора города, если город есть, то ваше ПО просто пропускает запрос дальше, ничего не делая. Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ . Пытался сохранить Cookie  с помощью js - setCookie.